# ToC: Change Spacing between Entries for LoF, LoT

Tags: table-of-contents

I am currently writing on a thesis and I need your help concerning the Layout of the ToC. 
The Text in the ToC is set to double spacing like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]
{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{blindtext}    
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false, 
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false] 
{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Quellcode}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{\lstlistingname verzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\newcommand{\algrule}[1][.2pt]{\par\vskip.5\baselineskip\hrule height 
 #1\par\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\doublespacing
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\listoftables
\pagebreak  
\listoffigures
\pagebreak

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\singlespacing
\begin{figure}
\centering
foo
\caption{foo}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\centering
 bar
\caption{bar}
\end{table}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to change and decrease the spacing between the entries for the LoT, LoF and the List for sourcecodes while the spacing for the rest of the entries in the ToC (sections, subsections) remains at double spacing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For the future, please provide a complete minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228)), beginning at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}` which recreates your issue but doesn't contain any unnecessary stuff.

Comment: Welcome! The code that you have provided is not compilable, partially because we do not have access to `titlepage.tex`. Is this really necessary? Also, `cleveref` should be loaded *after* `hyperref`.

Comment: @Troy, I edited the code, the `titlepage.tex` is not neccessary at all. In the original code the `cleverref` is loaded after `hyperref`. It should be working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky way could be done by manually inserting negative `\vskip` into the ToC. The adaption to your newly provided MWE is rather easy. Change the `\vskip-1em` into `\vspace{-1em}`. That works:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]
{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[
    unicode=true,
    pdfusetitle,
    bookmarks=true,
    bookmarksnumbered=false,
    bookmarksopen=false,
    breaklinks=false,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    backref=false,
    colorlinks=false] 
{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Quellcode}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{\lstlistingname verzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\newcommand{\algrule}[1][.2pt]{\par\vskip.5\baselineskip\hrule height 
 #1\par\vskip.5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagebreak
\doublespacing
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\listoftables
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-1em}}
\pagebreak  
\listoffigures
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-1em}}
\pagebreak

\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Quellcodeverzeichnis}
\pagebreak

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\singlespacing
\begin{figure}
\centering
foo
\caption{foo}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\centering
 bar
\caption{bar}
\end{table}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This somehow just works if i insert `\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-1em}` after `\tableofcontents` but not if for example I insert it after    `\listoftables`. If I set the value for `\vskip` to -5em the spacing between the header of the ToC and the entries gets even bigger. Is there maybe another way to do this?

Comment: @Cosimo there might (and most likely is), but I can't guess the documentclass and packages you use. So provide a complete MWE, and someone (maybe myself) might give a better answer.

Comment: I just tried to compile the MWE you posted in your answer with all the packages that I use in my document. Without all the packages included your solution works just fine. I deleted one package after the other and it seems like the hyperref package is the cause of the problems. I edited my original post so that you can see how I used this package. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @Cosimo I've updated my answer to incorporate all the packages you provided. Changing `\vskip` to `\vspace` works.

Comment: `\vspace` works just fine. It decreases the spacing between the entries for LoF and LoT successfully. Thanks for your help!